# TFS build - Project referring to the Older dlls instead of the new dllls

Tags: build, tfs

We have configured a new build definition for building solution in the project. This solution have multiple projects. The projects are set to copy the dlls to one common folder "Build" and the projects refering to each other use this location to refer the dependent Dll. After setting the Build definitin, build is working fine. But when I created some new classes in one of the project then the build started failing because the "Build" folder is having the older Dlls only which does not contain the class and while building TFS copies all the newly build dlls to the "Binaries" folder. and later replaces these dlls with the dlls from the "Build" folder which are older dlls. 
             I have tried several ways but still could not figure out that why the "Build" folder is not getting updated with the latest build Dlls. Please guild me, where am I missing the configuration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed this issue by manually deleting the Dlls from the "Build" folder on the server, so now the Build with new classes is working because the newly build dlls are not replaced by the copy operation from "build" folder.

Comment: So now during the build process nothing is copied into the "Build" folder, so that it is always empty?

Comment: No the Build Folder is updated with the new dlls, it was not overwrting the files somehow..

Answer (score 0):

You should check the project properties, maybe your output goes to another location depending on the configuration (Debug/Release) you are building.
Is the "Build" folder checked in in TFS? In that case the files are read-only during the build process and can't be overwritten by copy.

Why do you use this Build folder instead of adding a project reference insisde the solution? This would make it independent from the output location, because the process knows automatically where to search.

Comment: No the the Build Folder is not checked-in. And the main question is who is copying the dlls from the Build Folder to the Binaries folder after the Build process is done.

Comment: MSBuild should copy the results as defined in the project files (.csproj/.vbproj). Is it working on your developer machine? Maybe it is a security problem that MSBuild is not allowed to copy the files to the "Build" folder.
Do you have project references in your solution? There shouldn't be ones, because you are directly referencing the output dll in another location.